# Why should there be minimal work before MPI_Init?

Tags: mpi

The documentations for both MPICH and OpenMPI mention that there should be minimal amount of work done before MPI_Init or after MPI_Finilize:

> The MPI standard does not say what a program can do before an MPI_INIT or after an MPI_FINALIZE. In the MPICH implementation, you should do as little as possible.

What is the reason behind this?

To me it seems perfectly reasonable for processes to do a significant amount of calculations before starting the communication with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MPI_Init` documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Init.html) of MPICH is giving some hints:

> The MPI standard does not say what a program can do before an MPI_INIT or after an MPI_FINALIZE. In the MPICH implementation, you should do as little as possible. In particular, avoid anything that changes the external state of the program, such as opening files, reading standard input or writing to standard output.

BTW, I would not expect `MPI_Init` to do communications. These would happen later.

And the [`mpich/init.c` implementation](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/master/src/mpi/init/init.c) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software); you can study its source code and understand that [it is initializing](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/blob/master/src/mpi/init/init.c#L121)  some timers, some threads, etc... (and that should indeed happen really early).

> To me it seems perfectly reasonable for processes to do a significant amount of calculations before starting the communication with each other.

Of course, but these should happen after `MPI_Init` (but before some [`MPI_Send`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Send.html) etc).

On some [supercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer), MPI might use dedicated hardware (like [InfiniBand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand), [Fibre Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel), etc...) and there might be some hardware or operating system reasons to initialize it very early. So it makes sense to call `MPI_Init` very early. BTW, it is also given the pointers to `main` arguments and I guess that it would *modify* them before further processing by your `main`. Then the call to `MPI_Init` is probably the first statement of your `main`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it was worded in the like that in order to allow MPI implementations that spawn its ranks within `MPI_Init`. That means not all ranks are technically guaranteed to exist before `MPI_Init`. If you had opened file descriptors or performed other things with side effects on the process state, it would become a huge mess.

Afaik no major current MPI implementation does that, nevertheless an MPI implementation might use this requirement for other tricks.

EDIT: I found no evidence of this and only remember this from way back, so I'm not sure about it. I can't seem to find the formulation in MPI standard that you quoted from MPICH. However, the MPI standard regulates which MPI functions you may call before `MPI_Init`:

> The only MPI functions that may be invoked before the MPI initialization routines are called are `MPI_GET_VERSION, MPI_GET_LIBRARY_VERSION, MPI_INITIALIZED, MPI_FINALIZED`, and any function with the prefix `MPI_T_`.

Comment: From a performance point of view, before `MPI_Init()`, all the tasks (that might not all exist yet) do the very same computation and that can be seen as a lost opportunity for parallelism and hence inefficient.

Comment: Back in the days of the vector processors, Fujitsu MPI had a remote fork&exec syscall that was invoked in `MPI_Init()`, so there was only a single task (and very likely some limitations too) before the MPI initialisation. MOSIX might have done that too, but that is only a guess.